# Open 'Insert Hyperlink' menu in Excel through a clickable shape

Tags: excel, vba, button, hyperlink

I have a shape that should open the 'Insert Hyperlink' menu when clicked. I managed to insert the hyperlink directly to a cell, by using:

```
Range("Q11").Select
Activesheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:= Selection, Address:="filename"
```

However, I don't know the Address yet. I simply want to recreate the process of inserting a hyperlink like you would going through the buttons in the ribbon, but then from a clickable shape.

How could I do this?

Comment: Right Click on any cell and the menu for hyperlink appears. Do you need more customized option than that?

Comment: Yes, I want to skip the right click and insert hyperlink actions. Those two should be performed when clicking the button.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to call code line `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show` from the shape macro.

Comment: That is exactly it, thanks!