# Open 'Insert Hyperlink' menu in Excel office Add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I want to open the 'Insert Hyperlink' menu programmatically without right clicking the cell.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985342/open-insert-hyperlink-menu-in-excel-through-a-clickable-shape#:~:text=Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985342/open-insert-hyperlink-menu-in-excel-through-a-clickable-shape#:%7E:text=Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show)

this link shows the way to achieve this in vba, is there a similar way for opening hyperlink menu in Excel office Add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not yet an Office JS API similar to the Application.Dialogs API in VBA that can be used by an add-in to open Excel dialogs. Please consider logging a request for this API in the [Microsoft 365 Developer Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

An alternative might be to have the add-in provide UI similar to the Insert Hyperlink dialog either in the task pane or in a dialog.